# Can GitVersionTask be configured to only update specified Assembly*Versions and not others

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, gitversion

Looking at the documentation for GitVersion, it appears that there are options for only allowing GitVersion to set certain version while allowing others to stay under manual control. As an example, I would like to update the AssemblyFileVersion but not the AssemblyVersion. I have tried adding the following to my `csproj` file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <UpdateAssemblyInfo>true</UpdateAssemblyInfo>
    <GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>true</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and have updated my `AssemblyInfo.cs` file

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

but I still end up with both versions being set to 1.0.0.0.

Is this type of configuration possible using GitVersionTask? I can not find any good examples or clear documentation showing this type of setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitVersion allows for more customized configurations by using a `GitVersion.yml` configuration file. To create a GitVersion configuration file, in a command prompt, execute `GitVersion init` in your project/solution directory. This will open up a menu with options such as `Run getting started wizard`. Run the wizard and follow the prompts. A completely default file looks like this:

```
branches: {}
ignore:
  sha: []
```

This file uses the logic "if it's not set, use the default".

To ignore AssemblyVersion, add `assembly-versioning-scheme: None` to the beginning of the file and when GitVersion runs it will ignore AssemblyVersion and update everything else. Likewise, if you wanted to ignore AssemblyFileVersion, you would add `assembly-file-versioning-scheme: None` to the beginning of the file as well.

More information about `GitVersion.yml` can be found at http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/

Comment: Is this using gitversion task or the command line application?

Comment: belated comment - it doen't matter. The `gitversion.yml` file works everywhere.